# why the change event is not called?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I set the text of a input text with: `$('#rif').val('bla bla bla');`

Why if I add a `.change()` event on that input text is not called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `.change()` event is trigerred after user intervention on the input. You can trigger it manually though after changing the value of the input field:

```
$('#rif').val('bla bla bla').change();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the value programatically the `.change()` event will not fire. If you are setting the value yourself from code you need to trigger the `.change()` event yourself too.

```
$('#rif').change();
```

or using the longhand form:

```
$('#rif').trigger('change');
```